# Webkit Engine : html-tag and html-attribute-name while saving the source of a webpage

Tags: dom, webkit

Chrome converts all html tags and attributes to:

```
<div> : <span class="html-tag">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
id="elemId" :  <span class="html-attribute-name">id</span>="<span class="html-attribute-value">elemId
```

Just want to know :

Is there any javascript / python library that converts the modified html to the original format. These elements do not show up in the page source (in the browser). But when I save the page source, the saved file has these elements. This is not allowing me to extract text from the page.